# dojo class function override with button click

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to add an action to a function in a dojo class.

example of base class that is loaded when the page is opened.

```
dojo.provide("nusw.winMgr");
dojo.declare("nusw.winMgr", null, {

constructor: function......

open: function(parm){
   alert("This is the default action of the class");
  }
});
```

I want to change the behavior of the open function so that when it is called it calls another function + the default mapped function anytime it is called.

for this example lets say I want to add the following function to the default open function.

```
function alert2(){
alert("This is the updated open function class");
}
```

I am expecting the results to be

Alert message: This is the updated open function class

Alert message: This is the default action of the class

The functions are a more complex than the example given here but this is what I am trying to figure out.

I want to be able to call this script to update the default class function when a user clicks a button so I would be placing the logic in a javascript function.

I am new to dojo

Answer (score 0):

In fact in `dojo` like in `Javascript`, you can always attach a dynamic callback function to events, so here attach a dynamic callback function to the `open` event of your widget.

And in this function you can later write any new logic you want to write, you can even call another `function`, then just update this second function.

This is what you can do for example:

```
var secondFunction = function secondFunction() {
  alert("This is another logic added");
}
var openCallback = function openCallback(param) {
  alert("This is the default action of the class");
  secondFunction();
}

//Then in your widget
dojo.declare("nusw.winMgr", null, {
   constructor: function......
   open: openCallback()
});
```

Comment: This would work if I had more than read access to the file the base class is in.  That is why I am trying to do this with some sort of override / function update

Comment: @CodeSmack can you provide more details, have access to this widget via  registry or an id?

Comment: I am working with an application that I do not have control over but I need to add some test functionality to the existing application.  I need to figure out a way to override a function that is in one of the base classes of the application.  I need to update the behavior of the function, but just for my group.  I do have access to the application source.  They did provide me a way to inject my test updates and I have had success with that so far but I can not figure out how to override the base class for the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

Try [dojo/aspekt](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/aspect.html) to accomplish this. It may look like:

```
require(["dojo/aspect"], function(aspect){
    aspect.after(baseClassInstance, "open", function(){
        alert("This is the updated open function class");
    });
});
```

or

```
require(["dojo/aspect"], function(aspect){
    aspect.before(baseClassInstance, "open", function(){
        alert("This is the updated open function class");
    });
});
```